# Approximating a general rectangle partition by a guillotine partition

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

There is a rectangle $R$ partitioned into some axes-parallel rectangles:

[image]

The goal is to construct another partition of $R$ into rectangles, using only guillotine cuts.
That is: cut $R$ into two rectangle pieces using a horizontal or vertical end-to-end cut;
Then, cut one of the resulting rectangles into two rectangles using an end-to-end cut; and so on.

Each part in the resulting guillotine partition should contain at most a single rectangle from the original partition, like this (where $c_1$ is first guillotine cut, $c_2$ is the second guillotine cut, etc.):

[image]

In the above example, the cyan rectangle is split (by the first cut $c_1$). In fact, it is easy to see that in every guillotine partition of $R$, at least one rectangle must be split.

Is there always a guillotine partition in which each rectangle in the original partition is split *at most once?*

**NOTE**: Instead of requiring that all rectangles be cut at most once, we can require that a fraction of rectangles will not be cut at all. A natural question then is what fraction of rectangles we can "save" (keep uncut) in a guillotine partition. This question has been studied for over 20 years; see [Guillotine separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine_separation) for a survey. A short summary of current results:

- When all rectangles are unit squares, $n/2$ can be saved, and it is tight.
- When all rectangles are general squares, at least $n/40$ can be saved. There is no upper bound better than the $n/2$.
- For general rectangles, at least $n/(1+\log{n})$ can be saved.
- Pach and Tardos (2000) conjectured that a constant fraction of $n$ can be saved. This conjecture is still open.

Comment: To me the phrase "cuts that go from one end of an existing piece to its other end" does not have a clear meaning. It is not clear what is "an existing piece." You might try to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I edited the question - I hope it is clearer now

Comment: It is easy to see that $f(n)\ge s(n)$, where $s(n)$ is defined in [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689295/how-many-whole-rectangles-can-you-catch-in-a-grid), and $s(n)\ge \sqrt{n}$ by Proposition 2 from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689295/how-many-whole-rectangles-can-you-catch-in-a-grid/3704482#3704482).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Indeed, $s(n)$ relates to the setting where the partition is a grid, which is a special case of a guillotine partition, so $f(n)$ must be at least as large.